# Spring WS with jaxb null object in request

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

I have Spring WS to which i am sending request of Object `Request.java` class, if i hardcode value in jaxb class it is ok ( but this is not it..)
my soap request i test in SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cas="http://jakisadres.com/caservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cas:Request>
         <cas:atr1>some value</cas:machineName>
      </cas:Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and what i get is :

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns3:Response xmlns:ns3="http://jakisadres.com/caservice">
         <responseValue>response: null</responseValue>
      </ns3:CARevokeCertResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

my endpoint:

```
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "Request", namespace = "http://jakisadres.com/caservice")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Response revokeCert(@RequestPayload Request param) {
        String request= param.getAtr1();
        Resoponse response_ = new Response();
        response.setResponseValue("response: "+request);
        return response;
    }
```

and my jaxb marshaller class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "atr1"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
public class Request{

    protected String atr1;


    public String getAtr1() {
        return atr1;
    }

    public void setAtr1(String value) {
        this.atr1 = value;
    }

}
```

any clue what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your `atr1` element is in the default namespace and not in `http://jakisadres.com/caservice` namespace..your request should either be:

```
  <cas:Request>
     <atr1>some value</atr1>
  </cas:Request>
```

OR you can explicitly specify the namespace for `atr1` field